# Typescript "Object is possibly undefined" while assigning property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```js
cached.promise = mongoose
            .connect(MONGODB_URI as string, opts)
            .then(mongoose => {
                return mongoose;
            });
```

My editor underlines `cached` and gives an "Object is possibly undefined" error. Why is it doing this for an assignment? Shouldn't it not matter if `cached.promise` is undefined because the assignment operator is going to make it defined?

**Edit**:
To settle the debate in the comments, I'd like to point out that the selected answer worked for me. The change I made to the code to get it working was this:

```js
(cached as { promise: Promise<typeof mongoose> }).promise = mongoose
            .connect(MONGODB_URI as string, opts)
            .then(mongoose => {
                return mongoose;
            });
```

**Edit 2**: Wait, was that not a debate in the comments where everyone was saying the same thing, but rather just everyone correcting me? Now I feel like an idiot.

Comment: `cached` is potentially `undefined`, not `cached.promise`.

Comment: No no. It's not telling you that `cached.promise` might be undefined, it's telling you that *cached itself* might be undefined. E.g. `const foo = undefined; foo.whatever = 3; // boom!`. Also if there's no `promise` property on the type of cached that assignment will error too.

Comment: if `cached` undefined how can you set a property of it? I think that's what the editor is trying to tell you

Comment: *"My editor underlines cached and gives an "Object is possibly undefined" error. Why is it doing this"* - Because `cached` is possibly `undefined`.  Do you have any indication why that shouldn't be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor underlines `cached` because you are trying to assign a property to a variable that may not be defined at all.
You need to ensure `cached` variable is defined and is an object as cached may be potentially undefined in your context:

```js
if (typeof cached === 'object') {
  cached.promise = mongoose
    .connect(MONGODB_URI as string, opts)
    .then(mongoose => {
      return mongoose;
    });
}
```